# Using the output of NDSolve for the calculations

Tags: differential-equations

In the last question, I asked how to deal with the stiffness problem in my PDE system.

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
tmax = 200; r = 0.5; lambda = 0.3; P = 200; 

pdeV1 = D[V1[t, z1, z2], 
     t] + (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1])^2*Exp[r*t]*
     Exp[lambda*(z1 + z2)] + (1 + z1^2)*D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*
     D[V2[t, z1, z2], z1]*Exp[(r*t)]*Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] + 
    P*lambda*(D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2] + D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*z1^2)*
     Exp[(r*t)]*(Exp[lambda*z1] - 1) == 0;


pdeV2 = D[V2[t, z1, z2], 
     t] + (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2])^2*Exp[(r*t)]*
     Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] + (1 + z2^2)*D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*
     D[V1[t, z1, z2], z2]*Exp[(r*t)]*Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] + 
    P*lambda*(D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1] + D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*z2^2)*
     Exp[(r*t)]*(Exp[(lambda*z2)] - 1) == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{pdeV1, pdeV2,
   V1[tmax, z1, z2] == 
    P*Exp[(-lambda*z2)] - P*Exp[(-lambda*(z1 + z2))],
   V2[tmax, z1, z2] == P*Exp[(-lambda*z1)] - P*Exp[(-lambda*(z1 + z2))]


   },


  {V1, V2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, "MaxPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}}]

Show[Plot3D[V1[tmax, z1, z2] /. sol, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot3D[V2[tmax, z1, z2] /. sol, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Purple]]
```

However,  it is not really necessary for the first step in my problem. Probably, knowing the dynamics of V1, V2 (value functions) is more than enough to proceed.

It is unclear to me how could I use the output from the NDSolve to calculate new values u1,u2 of the system:

```
 NSolve[{
  u1[t, z1, z2] - 
     D[V1[tmax, z1, z2] , z1] *Exp[(r*t)]*Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] == 
    0 /. sol,
  u2[t, z1, z2] - 
     D[V2[tmax, z1, z2] , z2] *Exp[(r*t)]*Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] == 
    0 /. sol},
  {u1, u2},{z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, {t, 0, tmax} , ]
```

I'm am working out the correct system right. Any help will be appreciated. The output desired u1 vs time  (t) and u2 vs time (t)

Comment: Tried everything. In some reasons term D[V1[tmax,z1,z2], z1] always gives 0 in the next calculations. What could be the reason?

Comment: If you are looking for an analytical solution to your algebraic equations then you are suppose to use `Solve`? BTW, what are the fixed values for `z1` and `z2` to be able to solve for `u's` in term of `t`?

Comment: A tractable analytical solution is not feasible. We don't really want to solve it for u1,u2. The idea was, to take the output from the first NDSolve and to calculate. But, it obviously incorrect syntax to do that.

Comment: I am unable to understand. Could you please make it more clear?